# How to convert the following sequential model into a functional model in keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I am using the following sequential model in Keras.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(150, input_shape=(29,3)))
model.add(Dense(100))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Now, I want to write the same model in functional Keras. I tried to do it as follows.

```
input1 = Input(shape=(29,1))
x1 = LSTM(50)(input1)
input2 = Input(shape=(29,1))
x2 = LSTM(50)(input2)
input3 = Input(shape=(29,1))
x3 = LSTM(50)(input3)    
x = concatenate([x1,x2,x3])
```

However, the results I get are completely different. So, I am thinking the way I converted my original sequential model is incorrect.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: What do you mean the same model? This is a completely different model, it has 3 inputs while your original model has only one.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro yes, I think that is the problem I have. How can I define the input as in my sequential model using keras functional? I look forward to heraing from you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
inputs = Input(shape=(29,3))
outputs = LSTM(150)(inputs)
outputs = Dense(100)(outputs)
outputs = Dropout(0.2)(outputs)
outputs = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(outputs)

model = Model(inputs, outputs)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```